# Python command line argument option -d

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to figure out the python command-line option -d. From the documentation it says [-d Turn on parser debugging output](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-d).

But when I test, it shows me nothing but an argument:

### main.py

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    print(argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Execute in cmd:**

$ python main.py -d /path/to/file

**O/P:**

['-d', 'C:/Program Files/Git/path/to/file']

Here `-d` print as an argument. Can anybody tell me the purpose of the `-d` option and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` is **python** option, not yours. So proper invocation is

```
$ python -d main.py /path/to/file
```

Comment: Ok. But what is the purpose of -d, if I use -d what will extra things happen?

Comment: It's not much for you there. As per documentation `Turn on parser debugging output (for expert only, **depending on compilation options**).` so it may do nothing really. And even if it would trigger additional output it'd most likely be useless for you, unless you are debugging language parser (but then you do not need to ask what is it for :)